# SQLSERVER - Sacar números consecutivos faltantes y en otra columna la fecha

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

Tengo una tabla de pólizas con dos columnas, fecha y numero de póliza. El numero de póliza está en consecutivo pero necesito sacar las pólizas faltantes de ese consecutivo y agregarlas a una temporal, junto con la fecha. La fecha obvio no estará pero le pondría la fecha de la póliza siguiente que exista.

Los datos que tiene la tabla son similares a estos.

```
CREATE TABLE #PolizasSeguros(
    fec_fechamovto  datetime,
    num_Poliza      bigint
);

INSERT INTO #PolizasSeguros
VALUES( '20130813', 5320005031),
      ( '20130816', 5320005032),
      ( '20130826', 5320005033),
      ( '20130829', 5320005034),
      ( '20130831', 5320005037),
      ( '20130902', 5320005038),
      ( '20130903', 5320005041),
      ( '20130906', 5320005046),
      ( '20130903', 5320005039),
      ( '20130903', 5320005040),
      ( '20130907', 5320005048);
```

El resultado que espero debería ser este basándonos en los datos anteriores.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
        VALUES( CAST( '20130831' AS datetime), 5320005035),
              ( CAST( '20130831' AS datetime), 5320005036),
              ( CAST( '20130906' AS datetime), 5320005042),
              ( CAST( '20130906' AS datetime), 5320005043),
              ( CAST( '20130906' AS datetime), 5320005044),
              ( CAST( '20130906' AS datetime), 5320005045),
              ( CAST( '20130907' AS datetime), 5320005047)) Faltantes( fec_fechamovto, num_Poliza);
```

Les pongo una imagen de mis tablas como ejemplo, en la 1 es la tabla de polizas y la 2 la temporal. Espero sean datos suficientes para que me ayuden a encontrar la solución. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Amigo, te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask], 
[mre], 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Esas imagenes no parecen de SQL Server (el producto de Microsoft). ¿Estás seguro de que usaste la etiqueta correcta?

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios. Es una herramienta de manejo de bases de datos llamado DBeaver, en la maquina no tengo SQL de Microsoft, pero el DBeaver me funciona de la misma manera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un problema que se conoce como islas y huecos (*[gaps and islands](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/gaps-islands-sql-server-data/)* en inglés). Los grupos de datos consecutivos que tienes son las islas, mientras que los grupos de datos consecutivos faltantes son los huecos. Lo que buscas es rellenar los huecos con números consecutivos de acuerdo al valor máximo de la última isla.

Para empezar a solucionar tu problema, empecemos por obtener las islas. Para eso agregamos una columna que agrupe los consecutivos.

```
SELECT *,
        num_Poliza - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY num_Poliza) AS isla
FROM #PolizasSeguros;
```

Con ese resultado, ya podemos obtener los huecos y los agrupamos en rangos.

```
WITH Islas AS(
    SELECT *,
            num_Poliza - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY num_Poliza) AS isla
    FROM #PolizasSeguros
)
SELECT maximo + 1 AS inicio,
    LEAD( minimo) OVER( ORDER BY minimo) - 1 AS fin,
    LEAD( fecha) OVER( ORDER BY minimo) AS fecha
FROM (
    SELECT MIN( num_Poliza) minimo,
           MAX( num_Poliza) maximo,
           MIN( fec_fechamovto) AS fecha
    FROM Islas 
    GROUP BY isla)x;
```

Ya tenemos los datos necesarios, pero ahora necesitamos ver como los rellenaremos los huecos. Para eso necesitamos una tabla de números. En este caso, te comparto una función que devuelve una serie de números entre dos límites.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally](
    @Start  bigint,
    @End    bigint
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS( -- Asignar números consecutivos a cada fila
    SELECT TOP(@End - @Start + 1) --Limitar la cantidad real de filas generadas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) + @Start - 1 n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;
```

Una vez que tenemos nuestras herramientas, solo hay que combinar todo.

```
WITH Islas AS(
    SELECT *,
            num_Poliza - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY num_Poliza) AS isla
    FROM #PolizasSeguros
),
Huecos AS( 
    SELECT maximo + 1 AS inicio,
        LEAD( minimo) OVER( ORDER BY minimo) - 1 AS fin,
        LEAD( fecha) OVER( ORDER BY minimo) AS fecha
    FROM (
        SELECT MIN( num_Poliza) minimo,
               MAX( num_Poliza) maximo,
               MIN( fec_fechamovto) AS fecha
        FROM Islas 
        GROUP BY isla)x
)
SELECT f.fecha AS fec_fechamovto,
    t.n AS num_Poliza       
FROM Huecos f
CROSS APPLY fnTally( f.inicio, f.fin) t
WHERE f.fin IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY num_Poliza;
```

Comment: ¿La función sólo funciona en el dialecto de T-SQL?

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares con la sintaxis exacta que tiene ahora, sí. Hay elementos y funciones que está usando, que sólo están disponibles en T-SQL.

Comment: El código se puede adaptar a los principales manejadores de datos porque casi todo es parte del estándar SQL, pero sí hay varios elementos que hacen que solo  funcione en SQL Server.